# Why is only half of my image is not properly rendering?

Tags: rendering

Alright. I'm kinda new to blender, and this is the first time I stuck with it. I followed a simple tutorial on how to make a bear. On my final render, the top half of my image isn't rendering as it should.

[image]

It looks slightly blurred at the top starting at about the very center. I don't think I have any weird settings turned on that would've caused this.

If it helps my specs are 
GPU: AMD R9 270 
Processor: AMD A10-7850K

I'm using my GPU to render the image. I've tried rendering it with tiles and using the other option that renders the whole image sample by sample.




Edit: After some tests, I've determined I stopped the render too early. The samples didn't complete. Apparently the top takes longer to render for some reason. It solves itself after about 1000 samples.

Comment: it looks fine to me.. or maybe it's not very clear where i should be looking , did you change the depth of field settings in camera options?  are you using any compositor nodes?

Comment: It's barely visible. When I zoom in on the image, I can clearly see it. I haven't changed the depth of field settings, and I don't think I'm using compositor nodes

Comment: [i can see some blur](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b5jbT.png) outlining the bear , try increasing the number of samples, don't render the whole image just a small portion where you see the blur to test quickly.